# Writing to file throws TypeError: 'Nonetype' object is not iterable

Tags: python

A file 'modify.txt' contains three cities:

```
Mumbai
London
Berlin
```

When I use the `write()`, I get the error:

```
for line in lines:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

```
file_name = 'modify.txt'
with open(file_name, 'a') as my_modifications:
    lines = my_modifications.write("New York\n")

for line in lines:
    print(f"{line.strip()}")
```

Similar issue persists when I use integers in the `write()`, I get `'int' object is not iterable`.

My objective is to display the updated output from the text file after executing the write()

Comment: Always check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects): *"`f.write(string)` writes the contents of string to the file, __returning the number of characters written__."*

Comment: That's because writing to a file (`.write`) does not return a list of lines. What's the behaviour you're expecting?

Comment: What is you goal here? Do you want to write lines to a file, or read them? Why do you expect or even need `write` to return what was written? You already know that as you literally pass it to the method to write... (i.e. `"New York\n"`)

Comment: I've removed my answer since it was off target, but I point out, as edited, you must indent within a context manager, otherwise the file is already closed. I assume this was just a format issue.

Comment: I have modified the question to explain what I'm trying to achieve. Have eliminated the read() block of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments `f.write(string)` **returns the number of characters written**. This means that your variable `lines` is not iterable. That's why you get an error.

First step (write content to the file)

```
with open("modify.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write("New York\n")
```

Second step (read each line from the file)

```
with open("modify.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip())
```